# Unable to see UIImage once stored and sent to Server form CoreData?

Tags: ios8, base64, uiimagepickercontroller, converters, cgsize

The first part of the code is where the camera button is pressed but not before checking if a textfield has been filled, this then checks camera type. All normal here me thinks.Once the picture has been taken I then resize the image so that its of smaller size then convert it to a NSString to which then the NSString data is stored in CoreData and then sent off to a server to be shown on screen.

> This is the camera press button

```
-(IBAction)takePicture:(UIButton*)sender {

if (printedname.text.length ==0){

 UIAlertView*alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
 @"Please enter Name"message:@""delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:
 @"Dismiss"otherButtonTitles:nil];[alertshow];return;

}

UIImagePickerController *pictureTaker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

pictureTaker.delegate = self;

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
     pictureTaker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

} else if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]){

         pictureTaker.sourceType  = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

}

[self presentViewController:pictureTaker animated:YES completion:nil];}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)pictureTaker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

NSLog(@"%@", info);
NSString * mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

if([mediaType isEqual:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeImage]){

    [pictureTaker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    base64Image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    base64Image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(100.0f,60.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [base64Image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    base64Image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(base64Image, 1.0);
    base64string = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];

    NSLog(@" image (%@), width: %.0f, height: %.0f, scale: %0.2f, string len %lu",base64Image,base64Image.size.width,
          base64Image.size.height, base64Image.scale,(unsigned long)base64string.length); 
}

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(base64Image, self, NULL , NULL);

}
```

It seem to send ok save but kind of get's lost half way through, can anyone help as Iv been >trying to sort this out for days now, Iv included below the console output for you to see >aswell, thanks to anyone that can help.

```
UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.image";
UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = "<UIImage: 0x17056260> size 
{ 2448, 3264 }
orientation 3 scale 1.000000";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem with the code below:

```
if (self.base64Image!= nil){

    NSString *strImageData = [self.base64Image stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];

    NSString *param =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"photo=%@", strImageData];

    [values addObject:param];
}
```